# how to scrape angellist api by location

Tags: python, json, api, web-scraping

I have just got the access of angellist api token but i dont know how to scrape all companies from india(15505 Companies) https://angel.co/companies?locations[]=India
i think angellist api works on country id but on angellist api dacuments country id is not given .please help me how can i get country id

import requests

r = requests.get("https://api.angel.co/1/tags/[some id]/startups?access_token=[my token]")

data = r.json()

print data.keys()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tag id for India is 1647. You can look up tags with the /search endpoint.

Comment: thanks  ,do you know link to search startups founders name?